Why is TONKEEPER not force to MAINNET on Transaction
Why is tonwallet this case tonkeeper not force the transaction to be on mainnet when the transaction network argument has been setted?
This is my code:
    import { useTonWallet, useTonAddress, useTonConnectUI, CHAIN } from '@tonconnect/ui-react';

    const sendExternalTransaction = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setIseExternalFormSubmitting(true);
        try {
            const amountInNano = new TonWeb.utils.toNano(amountValueExternal).toString();
            const hexAddress = new TonWeb.utils.Address(addressReceiverExternal.address).toString(false);
            const transaction = {
                validUntil: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60,
                network : CHAIN.MAINNET,
                from : user.address,
                messages : [
                    {
                        address : hexAddress,
                        amount :  amountInNano
                    }
                ]
            };

            try {
                await tonconnect.sendTransaction(transaction)
            } catch (error) {
                toast('An error happend', config.toastSettings);    
            }
        } catch (error) {
            toast('An error happend', config.toastSettings);
        }
    }

This is the transaction class
    /**
     * Opens the modal window and handles the transaction sending.
     * @param tx transaction to send.
     * @param options modal and notifications behaviour settings. Default is show only 'before' modal and all notifications.
     */
    sendTransaction(tx: SendTransactionRequest, options?: ActionConfiguration): Promise<SendTransactionResponse>

export declare type SendTransactionFeatureDeprecated = 'SendTransaction';

export declare interface SendTransactionRequest {
    /**
     * Sending transaction deadline in unix epoch seconds.
     */
    validUntil: number;
    /**
     * The network (mainnet or testnet) where DApp intends to send the transaction. If not set, the transaction is sent to the network currently set in the wallet, but this is not safe and DApp should always strive to set the network. If the network parameter is set, but the wallet has a different network set, the wallet should show an alert and DO NOT ALLOW TO SEND this transaction.
     */
    network?: CHAIN;
    /**
     * The sender address in '<wc>:<hex>' format from which DApp intends to send the transaction. Current account.address by default.
     */
    from?: string;
    /**
     * Messages to send: min is 1, max is 4.
     */
    messages: {
        /**
         * Receiver's address.
         */
        address: string;
        /**
         * Amount to send in nanoTon.
         */
        amount: string;
        /**
         * Contract specific data to add to the transaction.
         */
        stateInit?: string;
        /**
         * Contract specific data to add to the transaction.
         */
        payload?: string;
    }[];
}


export declare enum CHAIN {
    MAINNET = "-239",
    TESTNET = "-3"
}

bot from address and receiver address has been converted to raw address (hex)
I tried to convert address into only mainnet address and bounceable and not bounceable. But after my experience it should be the hex format. To not have an address type that is defined on chain which hex is not

So what exactly are you asking about? If you'd like to suggest to change behavior of Tonkeeper, SO is not the right place to do so
